# Can't access axios in vuex Store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

Here is my store.js code:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios/dist/axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'mybase.com',
  timeout: 2000,
});

Vue.use(VueAxios, api)
Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  state: {
    name: null,
    YOB: null,
    gender: null,
    city: null,
    daily_goal: null,
    balance: null,
    today_video_count: 17,
    video_credit: 5,
  },
  mutations: {
    updateDailyGoal(state, value) {
      state.daily_goal = value;
    },
    addVideoCredit(state) {
      state.balance += state.video_credit;
    },
    reduceDonation(state, amount) {
      state.balance -= amount;
    },
    setVideoCount(state, count) {
      state.today_video_count = count;
    },
    initialize(state, profile) {
      state.name = profile.name;
      state.YOB = profile.YOB;
      state.gender = profile.gender;
      state.city = profile.city;
      state.daily_goal = profile.daily_goal;
      state.balance = profile.balance;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    submitVideoView({commit}, payload) {
      this.$http.post('/vid');
      commit('addVideoCredit');
    },
    setDailyGoal({commit}, value) {
      this.$http.post('/account/daily-goal', {daily_goal: value});
      commit('updateDailyGoal', value);
    },
    init({commit}) {
      this.$http.get('/account/profile').then(response => {
        commit('initialize', response);
      });
      this.$http.get('/account/vid-view').then(response => {
        commit('setVideoCount', response);
      });
    },
  },
  created() {
    dispatch('init');
  },
});
```

But it gives me error that undefined doesn't have post property which means that this.$http is not defined. How can I fix this?
Also here is my main.js:

```
import Vue from "nativescript-vue";
import App from "./components/App";
import store from "./store";

new Vue({
  store,
  render: (h) => h("frame", [h(App)]),
}).$start();
```

Any comments on how to improve this code would be highly appreciated. I really looked around so much but couldn't find any good document that would tell me how to properly set this up. Please note that I only want the init action to be dispatched once in the beginning of every user session/launching of app.

Comment: From the documentation of VUE-AXIOS it says that you should do like this : 

import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

Comment: so you mean I should change axios/dist/axios to just axios? because that doesn't help.

Comment: no, but maybe that Vue.use(VueAxios,axiox). 
but i dont really understand why using an axios wrapper. i can mark an answer how to use axios properly without any axios wrapper.

Comment: I don't insist on using it. actually I've removed that but my created doesn't seem to work. I also tried to move it to the main.js file but my data doesn't get initialized if you can post an answer that would also initialize data from some api that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to use an Axios wrapper for just simple HTTP requests. 
What you can do is import the Axios module in a file then making the requests directly through the Axios module. 
You can wrap it as a data adapter if you want.

```
import axios from 'axios';
const baseUrl = process.env.BASE_URL || '/';
export default {


 get(url, options) {
    return axios.get(`${baseUrl}${url}`, options)
      .then(response => response.data);
  },
  post(url, body, options) {
    return axios.post(`${baseUrl}${url}`, body, options)
      .then(response => response.data);
  },
  update(url, body, options) {
    return axios.put(`${baseUrl}${url}`, body, options)
      .then(response => response.data);
  },
  delete(url, options) {
    return axios.delete(`${baseUrl}${url}`, options);
  },
}
```

Name that file as EP/index.js for example
Then when in your vuex you can import that file below and use these functions, that's it.